# using HiGHS solver with highspy and pyomo

Tags: pyomo, highs

I'm attempting to run several models using the HiGHS solver with python/pyomo.  At some point a few months back, I had a few things running, but now it seems I'm at a standstill trying to get things working.  I'm running an older mac with macOS 11.7

Actions so far:

I installed the HiGHS solver from source using these [instructions](https://ergo-code.github.io/HiGHS/dev/installation/#Compile-from-source) (v1.5.3) and I can feed it .mps models from the command line and get results, so that is working.

However, when I installed `highspy` from PyPi, it appears to install OK, but crashes on import:

```
~ % pip3 show highspy
Name: highspy
Version: 1.5.3
Summary: Python interface to HiGHS
Home-page: https://github.com/ergo-code/highs
Author: 
Author-email: 
License: MIT
Location: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages
Requires: 
Required-by: 
~ % python3
Python 3.11.0 (v3.11.0:deaf509e8f, Oct 24 2022, 14:43:23) [Clang 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.30)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import highspy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/highspy/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .highs import (
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/highspy/highs.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .highs_bindings import (
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/highspy/highs_bindings.cpython-311-darwin.so, 2): Symbol not found: __ZN5Highs10clearModelEv
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/highspy/highs_bindings.cpython-311-darwin.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/highspy/highs_bindings.cpython-311-darwin.so
>>>
```

I figured there might be an integration issue w/ Python 3.11, so I tried the same in a Python 3.10 venv and got same result.

I'm pretty sure (though I'm not sure why as the executable is available on the CLI...) that I need to `import highspy` within a `pyomo` model to get connectivity to the solver.  I attempted a trivial model with/without that import and both failed.  The "import" one failed for reasons above and the non-import one coughs up:

```
pyomo.common.errors.ApplicationError: Solver <class 'pyomo.contrib.appsi.base.SolverFactoryClass.register.<locals>.decorator.<locals>.LegacySolver'> is not available (NotFound).
```

Comment: same problem here, did you find a solution ?

Comment: Not for the older OS (the answer below is still relevant).  It appears to work fine on more current Mac OS's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a little digging, I think this indicates the problem:

https://github.com/ERGO-Code/HiGHS/issues/1119

It sounds like distro versions of 1.5.3 for older generation OS X builds may be missing some include files and a fix is in-work.

Comment: Of note, highspy 1.7 is available in beta version as of earlier this month.  I'm not sure if it fixes the issue with older MacOS files (I'm using a different machine now), but it works well so far on my newer Mac.  https://pypi.org/project/highspy/1.7.1.dev1/